# Camel multicast aggregation with fastest route win

Tags: routes, header, apache-camel, aggregate, multicast

Is it possible in camel to create a multicast for n routes and from the n route whichever is the fastest decide the single aggregated value of the whole multicast?

So forexample:

```
from("direct:anywhere")
  .process(e -> { e.getIn().setHeader("isComplete", false)})
  .multicast()
    .parallelProcessing(true)
    .to("direct:somewhere", "direct:somewhere2")
    .end()
  .aggregate(header("isComplete"))
    .completion(header("isComplete").isEqualTo(true))
    .completionSize(1); // do i need this at all if i want the fastest route?
  .choice()..... // based on the fastest route's logic do something else with the exchange.getIn() headers or body
```

I tried aggregationStrategies for both the multicast and the aggregate but they don't even called just once with a null oldExchange.

Somehow the aggregate can not see the header changes inside the multicasted routes or the aggregate predicate is bad?

Comment: Yeah remove that aggregate eip, and just set aggregation strategy on the multicast and return the old exchange as the answer (= the first one)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer it was almost okay but I had to return the new exchange, i am setting exchange.in.header values in the sub routes to calculate something and push it to the "coice" part however!! the multicast still waits for the slower route to complete it does not end when the faster route completes, any ideas? the aggregationStrategy called twice [null, exchange1] then [exchange1, exchange2] but at the end...so the main question is how to interrupt a multicast with a subroute completion?

Comment: oh i found your answer to another thread: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Interrupt-MultiCast-waiting-td5766701.html it's really sad that there is no way for this

Answer (score 0):

it seems that none of the camel components (split, multicast) supports normal programatical interruption so one should create a decomposition of routes and aggregate them back manually with an external help forexample a Map storing/getting results

```
R1 (multicast to seda routes) -> R2 (timeout logic) -> R4 - get results from a Map(either R2 timeouted or R3 put there something faster) 
   \                                                  ^     should be threadsafe
    \                                                /  
     ˇ  R3 quickly found a result for the problem   /
```